# Hide a div based on Select option value in jquery

Tags: jquery, shopify

I need to hide the div which shows up as "**Default title**". This is generated from an app in shopify which will only shows up once the page has completely loaded. So i'm having hard time trying to hide the div which contains "Default title".

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".shopthelook_variants_single:contains(Default Title)").filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) ==  'Default Title'
    }).remove();
});
```

Rendered HTML:

```
 <div class="js-ctl-product-card-form-holder ctl-product-actions-wrapper js-stl__product__add-to-cart">
   <div class="ctl-product-actions js-ctl-product-card-form">
      <div class="select-size-wrap">
         <div class="selectize-control select-size">
            <select class="shopthelook_variants shopthelook_variants_single" data-product-id="6615731634254" data-product-index="2" name="product_collection_form[products][2][variants]">
               <option value="39409911857230" data-price="12.00" data-formatted-price="<span class=money>$12.00</span>">Default Title</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ctl-product-actions-button">
         <input type="hidden" name="productCodePost" class="pdp-size-value" value="6615731634254">
         <input type="hidden" name="product_collection_form[products][2][quantity]" size="3" class="shopthelook_quantity" maxlength="3" data-product-id="6615731634254" value="1" min="0">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn--primary js-action shopthelook_add-to-cart btn--add-to-basket add_to_cart" data-add-to-cart-text="Add to cart" data-sold-out-text="Sold out" data-product-id="6615731634254">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Default title` appears to be the text within an `option` element, so it would appear your selector isn't targeting the right thing. To help you debug this we need to see all the relevant HTML, not a screenshot of the output.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for `$(".shopthelook_variants_single").filter(function() { return $(this).find("option:selected").text() == 'Default Title' }).remove()`. But as @RoryMcCrossan says I strongly recommend that you include the actual rendered code itself and not an image of it.

Comment: You can hide by data-product-id. Which is unique for all products.

Comment: @vaibhavkanmeriya that is not a very dynamic solution. He would have to know all of the ids of those selects that only has the option with Default Title.

Comment: if you able to share the page, then someone check Ids, and classes and able to share working solution.

Comment: @Onkar I don't follow what you are saying. Why do you believe it would be enough to check id and classes in order to provide a solution.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen if you check the HTML into snapshot then you realize there is one unique class on the element that has only a single default title but can't able to confirm it from the snapshot. need to check on the page using the inspector

Comment: @Onkar What class is it you think is unique?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen on select element `shopthelook_variants_single`  is only added on those ones, where default title is as a variant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236846/discussion-between-carsten-lovbo-andersen-and-onkar).

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I tried ur answer but it didnt work , should i add your code in document.ready ? because the app adds code only once the page is completely loaded

Comment: I think you need to use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` methods to check the class and once loaded run the same code.

Comment: @webdevaj Yer you can try that, but without your code it's hard to give you a good answer.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen $(".shopthelook_variants_single").filter(function() { return $(this).find("option").text() == trim('Default Title') }).hide(); this is what i tried in document.ready

Comment: @Onkar disagree, since it's build with shopify then document ready should be enough, else he has to add the check somewhere else. setInterval can be the root of many problems where code work and don't work from time to time

Comment: @webdevaj Why do you use `trim('Default Title')`?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i thought the empty space can cause an issue so used trim

Comment: @webdevaj It should not, I suggest that you add the rendered html to the question, then we can help you a lot better.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i have added please check now

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej are you sure, it works?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej No im not jealouse, second IF it works why do you write `This can work` it makes it sound like you are not sure. Third, you don't provide any explanation to why this solves the problem and what was wrong. How do you expect the op to learn?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej sry your code didnt work

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej now any update, bro?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej ThIs is generated from an shopify app that comes only after the page gets fully loaded so my guess is document.ready event is not listened

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  $(".shopthelook_variants_single").filter(function() { return $(this).find("option").text() == 'Default Title' }).hide();
}); i tried this still it didnt work

Comment: `var shopLook = setInterval( function(){
  if( !$(".shopthelook_variants_single").length ){
   return;
  }
  clearInterval(shopLook);
  $(".shopthelook_variants_single").filter(function() { return $(this).find("option:selected").text() == 'Default Title' }).remove();

 }, 500);`  you need to check like this, if anything is not works at end

Comment: @Onkar your code worked

Comment: one thing to remember using on that products only where the same classes are added to the page, otherwise this run again and again

Comment: or simply add following code line bellow it `setTimeout(function(){ clearInterval(shopLook); }, 3000)`. so the flowing execution stopped after 3 seconds automatically

Comment: @Onkar i coudnt understand the part "one thing to remember using on that products only where the same classes are added to the page, otherwise this run again and again" what shall happen any critical issue can occur ?

Comment: This means to say, `setInterval` code runs again and if the `shopthelook_variants_single` is not found to it. so if you add the code to theme.liquid so it runs on the all pages like collections, blogs and homepage, etc where this class is never appended by APP.

Comment: So try to add it only for product page like {% if template contains 'product' %}code goes here{% endif %}

Comment: @Onkar ok got it so u mean only add it in product.template ,

Comment: Yes, on product template where APP adds the code for shopthelook